# Murder of the President - Part 1

Tags: mystery

I am trying something new. This detective riddle/brainteaser will be the first of 5+ parts in a case to solve the murder of the president. Each part will give you a clue (usually a place to go for the next clue) and you must solve the clue. Use all knowledge you have of cryptography, ciphers, etc. This case is meant to take place in the present day, so all politicians, celebrities, places, etc. are what they are now. Please post your answers in spoiler tags.

Here's the riddle:

The President of the United States has been murdered and you are on the case.
The date is November 5, 2014 at 4:03 p.m. when you begin to investigate.

Here's what you know so far:

> Location: Oval Office, Washington D.C., President found dead at his desk
>   Time of Death: November 5, 2014 at 1:09 p.m.
>   Body Found: 1:34 p.m. 
>   Death Wound: Stabbed in the heart (immediate death)
>   Killer's Entrance: Used a rope to get to the window; the window was unlocked from the inside (possible sabotage).
>   Killer's Escape Route: Out of the window
>   Evidence: No fingerprints or other DNA evidence, only a typed, coded note left on the President's desk.

Here is the note:

> Ulea jsbl ha LDY Zvbaodlza H
>   Fvby Mypluk,
>   Aol Rpssly

Scribbled in the corner of the note are two words: *Romans 7*

It's up to you to decode this message and find out where this clue leads you.

Good Luck

---

*Note

I will be posting Part 2 in one to two days. I will select the correct answer for Part 1 before, but I will post the answer for Part 1 if no one gets it*

Comment: Don't post the answer! It'll ruin it for others who want to go back and figure it out!

Comment: Obviously that **typed** note was a result of the president falling flat on his face onto the keyboard!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4myprTrw

Comment: I know, I was making a joke.

Comment: @warspyking I'm going to post it in the answer to each part but only if no one gets the right answer

Comment: Speaking of which, I have a feeling that Romans 7 the biblical chapter is going to be significant in one of these later levels.

Comment: @JoeZ. You never know.

Comment: I've made chain riddles like this one before. Every scrap of information, even red herrings from previous levels, get used eventually.

Comment: @JoeZ. You have to use all your resources to solve these puzzles. These comments might even be able to help people.

Comment: Plot Twist: Secret service will arrest you before you get to part 2.

Comment: The real question here is what font was the note in? If it is Ariel or Times New Roman, then we have a professional. But if it is in Wingdings, may God have mercy on us all for we have a madman!

Comment: In order to make this go smoothly, I'd suggest possibly editing in a link to each subsequent part as time goes on?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why they down voted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The secret note reads

> Next clue at EWR Southwest A
>  Your Friend,
>  The Killer
>
>  I'm not quite sure why though, Romans is a hint to the Caesar cipher, but I'm not sure what the significance of 7 is. The key for deciphering is 19, but I reached that after a few tries.
>
>  EWR Southwest A looks like an airport code, and matches [the Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR)](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-airport-map.html). Southwest A would likely mean the southwest part of the A terminal on the map.

Comment: Good answer. The 7 means 7 to the left. I also forgot to ask in the question where you have to go based on the note. I just edited it. Sorry

Comment: @michaelpri Yeah, that makes sense. 19 one way or 7 the other.

Comment: Also, do you know what the EWR Southwest A stands for?

Comment: @michaelpri Updated the answer.

Comment: Correct. I'll mark this answer right tomorrow because I want to let others have a try.

Comment: Snap you edited! I just answered with the location of the next clue D: I thought I could beat you to it! Well I tried to answer your question @mich

Comment: Interestingly enough, Romans 7 in the Bible's heading is "Released from the Law..."

Answer (score 2):

The note says:

> Next clue at EWR Southwest A
>  Your Friend,
>  The Killer
>
>  The next clue is at the southwest airport;
>  Newark, NJ - EWR

Thanks Nit for providing an answer with the text of the note. Upvote his answer!

Answer (score 2):

The note reads

> `Next clue at EWR Southwest A`
>  `Your Friend,`
>  `The Killer`
>
>  'Romans 7' hints that a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) was used (named after the *Roman* emperor Julius Caesar), with a shift of *7* to the right. To unshift, we must either shift 7 to the left, or 26 - 7 = 19 to the right.
>
>  'EWR' is the IATA code for Newark Liberty International Airport. Southwest Airlines uses terminal A at Newark, so we may need to take a look there.

Comment: Also the southwest part of terminal A