# Murder of the President - Part 2

Tags: mystery

This is Part 2 of the Murder of the President brainteaser/riddle series. If you have not already, you might want to see the answer for [Murder of the President - Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/murder-of-the-president-part-1) posted by Nit before you begin to work on Part 2. Each part will give you a clue (usually a place to go for the next clue) and you must solve the clue. This part will have two puzzles you have to solve. Use all knowledge you have of cryptography, ciphers, etc. This case is meant to take place in the present day, so all politicians, celebrities, places, etc. are what they are now. Please post your answers in spoiler tags.

Here's the riddle:

You arrive at the Newark, NJ airport and head to the Southwest part of terminal A. Once you arrive, you begin to look around the area. Nothing seems unusual. You glance at a TV and notice that, surprisingly, no one is reporting about it yet. They've done a good job keeping this silent. You check your watch. 7:30 p.m. You begin to look around again. As you scan the walls for any clues, a man bumps into and mutters something you vaguely hear as 'End of six.' You start walking around and at about 7:36 p.m. you spot a briefcase isolated from everyone. You head over to investigate. The briefcase has three number locks, the first has eight digits, the second has four digits, and the last one has two digits. You turn the briefcase over and see a sticky note with some scribbled words on it.

Here's what it says:

> 1. C (bytes)
> 2. ADIF
> 3. Deep Thought

After you open the briefcase there is a New International Version Bible.

What are the three codes? What should you do with the Bible?
What should you look for?

Good Luck.

---

*Note
I will be posting Part 3 in one to two days. I will select the correct answer for Part 2 before, but I will post the answer for Part 2 if no one gets it*

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18522/discussion-on-question-by-michaelpri-murder-of-the-president-part-2). Please refrain from discussing the question here in comments; instead, please discuss it in chat. If you'd like to request clarification from the author or have another remark, comments are fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's decode the briefcase numbers first.

You mention that the codes are 8 numbers, 4 numbers, and 2 numbers respectively. My best guesses as to how to solve them are as follows.

1. There's nothing quite relevant to the letter "C" (in the form of the programming language, the roman numeral, or anything else) that has 8 digits in it. However, the hint mentions "bytes" and a byte is 8 bits. So we can try converting "C" into ASCII and then representing it in binary.

> This gives `01000011`, which is an 8-digit code.

2. ADIF is not a well-known acronym relating to anything. However, all the letters come before J in the alphabet. So, we can try converting "ADIF" using the A = 1, B = 2 cipher.

> This gives `1496`, which is a 4-digit code.

3. A quick Google of Deep Thought reveals that the name belongs to [one of the chess machines built by IBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Thought_%28chess_computer%29). However, no two-digit numbers stand out as especially important (for example, finding a checkmate in 37 moves, winning 63 games in its lifetime, being built in '88).

   A second result reveals that Deep Thought is also the name of [the computer in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Deep_Thought) that was given the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything.

> Here, the two-digit number that stands out is `42`.

Thus, the three codes to the briefcase are:

> `01000011` `1496` `42`

---

Now that we've opened the briefcase, there's a New International Version Bible inside.

You mention that you vaguely hear a phrase from somebody as "end of six", but that phrase is not homophonous or phonetically similar to any single word I could find, so it can probably be interpreted as "end of six" literally.

Referring back to the "Romans 7" clue in the first riddle, my first guess is that "end of six" refers to the end of [Romans 7:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+7:6&version=NIV), which reads in the NIV as follows:

> <sup>**6**</sup> But now, by dying to what once bound us, we have been released from the law so that we serve in the new way of the Spirit, and **not in the old way of the written code.**

So if my interpretation is correct, you must do something with one of the written codes, possibly the one from part 1. I still haven't figured out what, though.

Alternatively, it could simply have referred to the "end of six minutes", as you mentioned that he found the briefcase at 7:36 PM, six minutes after 7:30.

Comment: Fantastic! Everything is correct. I will mark this correct tomorrow.

Comment: Everything I've *answered* is correct, perhaps, but I still haven't been able to figure out what I'm supposed to do that's "not in the old way of the written code".

Comment: You will soon .

Comment: Perhaps it's a hint that the first clue is an acrostic, spelling 'NYT'. So what's up with the _New York Times_?