# Murder of the President - Part 3

Tags: mystery

This is Part 3 of the Murder of the President brainteaser/riddle. If you have not already, you might want to see the answer for [Murder of the President - Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/murder-of-the-president-part-1) posted by Nit and the answer for [Murder of the President - Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3845/murder-of-the-president-part-2) posted by Joe Z. Each part will give you a clue and you must solve it. Use all knowledge you have of cryptography, ciphers, past puzzles, etc. You should also use Google. This case is meant to take place in the present day, so all politicians, celebrities, places, etc. are who they are now. Please post your answers in spoiler tags.

Here's the riddle:

You open up the Bible to Romans 7:6 which reads

> <sup>**6**</sup> But now, by dying to what once bound us, we have been released from the law so that we serve in the new way of the Spirit, and not in the old way of the written code.

On the page after this verse, there are 8 sticky notes, some typed, some handwritten, all coded (for this part, all typed notes will be **bold**, and all handwritten ones will be *italics*). At the top of the page, there is some writing in marker.

> *Every <sup>4</sup>/<sub>16</sub>
>
>
>   WDFPSSDOQWXLVMKYSGFACRVLKJJPDDDHMNNAZXZBQWSEXNXTKJDIXXXC*

Then the notes read:

> **#1 Romans
>
>   UDQF BNEQRS TBNT VT QHJGRDH**

---

> *#2 Snake
>
>   VCEP SNACPW YWWP NLBU NTKFFNY*

---

> *#3 Cow
>
>   FWBFZ FQ IEH EOHHFGTKWH AHHH*

---

> *#4 Firetruck
>
>   TDEGYJ NHGKW AX NZZ FZXAWHN UGXP*

---

> **#5 Gorilla
>
>   UJEKQD UOGWN UE UOT UXDDFJI UUGQ**

---

> *#6 Tree
>
>   NZNX CK GJZGWJ NZJ HIJWJWL HQOW*

---

> *#7 APPLE
>
>   HE JA YIU FQSJDIGQB JMA MVDTDJE QDP YIYHFD OYDQ*

---

> **#8 Dog
>
>   CDB EGL EI ALT DVDUK ESERL**

---

What do these codes mean? What do they say? Where should you go next?

Good Luck

---

*Note I will be posting Part 4 in one to two days. I will select the correct answer for Part 3 before, but I will post the answer for Part 3 if no one gets it*

Comment: I think you have a copy/paste error in your last paragraph (where you say you will be posting part 3 in a couple of days...)

Comment: Well, I've worked out the bit in marker which is more than I usually manage so I'm calling this a personal victory!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before trying to break the other eight codes, it would be a good idea to figure out what the message written in marker says first.

> Every <sup>4</sup>⁄<sub>16</sub>
>
> WDFPSSDOQWXLVMKYSGFACRVLKJJPDDDHMNNAZXZBQWSEXNXTKJDIXXXC

If we take every fourth letter in the large string of letters, we get "POLYALPHABETIC", which most likely means that the next eight codes are encoded using some sort of polyalphabetic cipher.

If we then apply the [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) (the most common form of polyalphabetic cipher) to each of the codes on the sticky notes with their respective keys, we get the following:

> `1. CODE NUMBER FIVE IS CORRECT` 
>  `2. CODE NUMBER FIVE ISNT CORRECT` 
>  `3. CHECK IN THE PRESIDENTS DESK` 
>  `4. NUMBER SEVEN IS THE CORRECT CLUE` 
>  `5. NUMBER THREE IS THE CORRECT CLUE` 
>  `6. THIS IS BEFORE THE CORRECT CLUE` 
>  `7. GO TO THE PENINSULA TWO HUNDRED AND THIRTY NINE` 
>  `8. YOU ARE AT THE WRONG PLACE`

A bunch of mutually contradictory statements! What do we do?

As always, look to the Bible. Recall in my answer to part 2, that the key to the puzzle was the *end* of Romans 7:6:

> <sup>**6**</sup> But now, by dying to what once bound us, we have been released from the law so that we serve in the new way of the Spirit, and **not in the old way of the written code.**

Five of these codes were handwritten. If we throw these out, then we are left with:

> `1. CODE NUMBER FIVE IS CORRECT` 
>  `5. NUMBER THREE IS THE CORRECT CLUE` 
>  `8. YOU ARE AT THE WRONG PLACE`

Which tells us that we are at the wrong place, and we need to check inside the President's desk. Back to the scene of the crime we go!

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious about this answer, though, since the President's desk is "the old way" (as in, an old place that was already visited) and it's also one of the handwritten codes.

Comment: Brilliant! Another fantastic answer!

Comment: Can't wait for the next one. :P