# Murder of the President - Part 5

Tags: cipher, mystery

This is Part 5 of the Murder of the President brainteaser/riddle series. If you have not already, check out the answers for [Murder of the President - Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/murder-of-the-president-part-1) posted by Nit, [Murder of the President - Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3845/murder-of-the-president-part-2) and [Murder of the President - Part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/murder-of-the-president-part-3) both posted by Joe Z., and [Murder of the President - Part 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/murder-of-the-president-part-4) posted by el jefe.  Each part will give you a clue and you must solve it. This part will have several clues. Use all knowledge you have of cryptography, ciphers, past puzzles, etc. You should also use Google. This case is meant to take place in the present day, so all politicians, celebrities, places, etc. are who they are now. Please post your answers in spoiler tags.

---

Here's the riddle:

You arrive at the London NYC Hotel at 2:26 a.m. You've already called the staff at the hotel to let them know you were coming. On the way up, you were beginning to hear reports that the President was murdered. You head up to room 118. You look around for a bit until you find a box under the covers. On top of the box is a note.

It says

> nvnmjoonhenuan
>   m<sup>**2**</sup>m
>   121
>   0+1
>   ttfflhesi

You check out the padlock. It is a one 5 digit code. Under the box there is another note.

> Padlock:
>   ZUTYS

---

After you figure out this code, you open up the box and find, of course, 6 coded notes. Some notes are typed, others are handwritten. (Italics will indiacte *handwritten* and bold will indicate **typed**)

Here are the notes

> **#1
>
>   ERP BTRCBIV PTUKU GTI CUBL**

---

> *#2
>
>   WAPHFS RPL MU UMK SQOF GWAWFGX UCTME UPCG*

---

> **#3
>
>   M DT AJF MMUPIS - YQ**

---

> *#4
>
>   SAQEHY WQG NT XLF VMOIA DUWI*

---

> **#5
>
>   BVB YPPX LEXDK NJ**

---

> *#6
>
>   VVHC ASL FNOXIS JETM ZVVOIU ZWTJPK
>
>   LLIFVFXZIDN*

What is the code to get into the box? What do all the notes mean?

Good Luck.

Hint:

> The messages are coded using the method and seed answered by el jefe. The sequence of numbers is continuous (it doesn't restart for each message). Also,  you must add one to every zero in the sequence

---

*Note: I will be posting Part 6 (the final part) in one to two days. I will select the correct answer for Part 5 before, but I will post the answer for Part 5 if no one gets it*

Comment: It's really nice of the killer(s) to leave clues like this to help out the investigation.

Comment: @Bachrach44 It really is convenient.

Comment: I'm confused already. Is the London NYC hotel in London or is it in New York City?

Comment: @A E New York I believe.

Comment: @Bachrach44 convenient for the investigators, sure, but not for the President!

Comment: @AE Its in New York

Comment: @hosch250 Yes good job

Comment: @michaelpri Do you add a 1 in the process of making the random numbers, or just decoding?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 While you are making random numbers

Comment: @michaelpri Do you start at 121 or 464?

Comment: @michaelpri I got `ALL AOPZAHP IRPJP ANG APAI`... My random numbers `464 1523116 72515 652 2513`

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 464

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 Your numbers are different than mine. I had `464 528 etc.`

Comment: 464^2 is 215296 and you have to add a preceding zero. [Description](http://www3.nd.edu/~mcbg/tutorials/2006/tutorial_files/randomNum/howItworks.html) Also, mind if I start chat?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 Yeah you can start one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18747/discussion-between-michaelpri-and-quynguyen2013).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the decoded notes. *Italics for handwritten*, **bold for typed**.

> **#1: ALL WRITTEN NOTES ARE TRUE**
>  *#2: NUMBER ONE IS THE ONLY CORRECT TYPED NOTE*
>  **#3: I AM THE KILLER - VP**
>  *#4: NUMBER SIX IS THE RIGHT CLUE*
>  **#5: YOU WONT CATCH ME**
>  *#6: PREZ TOD WINTER FALL SUMMER SPRING CHEESESTEAK*

So I suppose:

> Our next stop is Hotel Four Seasons in Philadelphia (as in Philadelphia cheesesteak). Also, the VP is off our list of suspects.
>  "PREZ TOD" must refer to the President's time of death, which was November 5, 2014 at 1:09 p.m. That's most likely our clue for the room number (109 maybe?)

About decrypting the messages:

> The notes are encrypted with a [vigenére cipher](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere.php), using the sequence of pseudorandom numbers obtained by using a variation of John von Neumann's middle square method using 121 as a seed, taking three numbers from the end (offset by one) and replacing all zeroes with ones. For those interested, [here](https://gist.github.com/Kaivosukeltaja/1f1921dba9e3d3c9f2a6) is the ugly but working Python implementation I ended up with.

Answer (score 10):

For the note on the top of the box

> "nvnmjoonhenuan" is an anagram of "John von Neumann", and "m2m" refers to the middle square method of pseudorandom number generation he created.  121 is likely a seed number for this PRNG. Also, "ttfflhesi" is an anagram of "shift left." "0+1" may refer to the loops of addition test used as a computing benchmark, signifying that one should take the previous number and add 1.

Not sure about note under box yet.  Will try again later.

Comment: All your anagrams are right. For the 0+1 part, you don't always have to add one to the previous number, just when it's zero.

Answer (score 6):

The number under the box is:

> 16728
>  this number is 26 - (position in alphabet, with  A = 0 and Z = 25).  For example, 26 - Z = 1.

Comment: Correct good job this is starting to become a group effort